# How to sort time by meridiem(AM/PM) in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I have time with meridiem(AM/PM).
For example,

I have time

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11:00 AM
    [1] => 6:00 AM
)
```

So after sorting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6:00 AM
    [1] => 11:00 AM
)
```

And if I have:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 11:00 AM
        [1] => 6:00 PM
    )
```

So sorting will be:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 11:00 AM
        [1] => 6:00 PM
    )
```

I have tried with

sort($arr,SORT_LOCALE_STRING);

and

sort($arr,SORT_NUMERIC);

But not worked.

Any solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any special reason for using strings to store time values? Is this raw user input? Otherwise you should never user strings for that! Do you have the real time values *(integer timestamps or `DateTime` objects)* available to you?

Comment: I would just take unix timestamp, sort them, and show them in date('g:i a') format when displaying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
   return (strtotime($a) > strtotime($b));
});
```

Comment: Yeah, It is working. but will it work if i have more than two timestamps? :)

Comment: but it will be slower than just taking unix timestamp nevertheless ;)