# Sorting laravel collection for times

Tags: php, laravel

Sorting a unique collection by value. I've tried sortBy but instead of the key need to sort by the value

```
return ($c->flatten()->unique());
```

Output: Need to go in chronological order

```
{"0":"9am","1":"10am","2":"11am","3":"1pm","4":"2pm","5":"5pm","10":"3pm","14":"12pm"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $c is the collection you meant, this should work:

```
$sorted = $c->sortBy(function($value, $key) {
  return strtotime($value);
});
```

Sources:

- [Laravel 5 Collections Sorting](https://stillat.com/blog/2018/04/22/laravel-5-collections-sorting-a-collection-based-on-a-key-value-with-sortby)
- [How to sort time by meridiem (AM/PM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35764737/how-to-sort-time-by-meridiemam-pm-in-php)